# how to share our ipad app for social networks like fb,twitter,etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ipad

like web project where we can share to socialnetworks by cliking on fb share/like button ,tweet button. i want to do the same thing in my ipad app.please any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use each social networks API individually, or you can use [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/).

ShareKit is a lot simpler, and easier to use, but there are very few limitations, but mostly it does everything you need it to. And the limitations are outweighed by the easy of use. (you'll still need to register as a developer on the social networks you want to support, there is a  tutorial on the website, and explanation in the code)

Answer (score 0):

Just read the documentation of the twitter and Facebook API, then use the REST interface to interact with the service.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to make the application which integrates facebook and twitter

USe the following link for doing so

[1. For Twitter](http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone)

[2. For Facebook](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app)

hAPPY iCODING...